# coldfusion null pointer exception in cfloop

Tags: coldfusion

I'm getting an issue as "Error Occurred While Processing Request
The system has attempted to use an undefined value, which usually 
indicates a programming error, either in your code or some system code.

Null Pointers are another name for undefined values."

I verified all posts related to NPException & most of the issues are related to cfquery, cfhttp......This issue is with in cfloop iteration in cfc function (Y)
I have two functions X & Y. Y is called by X multiple times with in the loop. This loop is in cflock tag with timespan=5

```
function X :
============
<cfset Var array = getXML()>
<cfargument name="searchOnly" type="boolean" required="false">
<cfset Var i = "">
inside loop Y method is called
<cflock scope="Session" type="exclusive" timeout="5">
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen( array )#" index="i">
<cfset fields = Y( array[i], Arguments.searchOnly )>
</cfloop>
</cflock>
===========

function Y :
============

<cffunction name=“Y”>
<cfargument name="root" required="true">
<cfargument name="searchOnly" type="boolean" required="false">
<cfset Var i = "">
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen( Arguments.root.XMLChildren     )#">
<cfset childNode = Arguments.root.XMLChildren[i]> ---> this line causes   an error


<cfif Arguments.root.XMLName neq "match">
<!--- Recursive call --->
<cfset Y( labeledElements, Y( childNode ) )>
</cfif>

Is there any issue with Recursive call with in the same cfloop.
</cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

Variable i is declared in these two cffunctions, is this raising any issue with same variable name i. Please share your thoughts

Comment: In Function X, `Arguments.searchOnly` appears to be undefined.  However, that would give a different error message.

Comment: @DanBracuk If you pass in an argument that is not declared in the function, CF ignores it. But he doesn't use the value anyway, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: What does `Aguments.root` look like when the exception is thrown? Use `try`/`catch` with `<cfdump var="Arguments.root"><cfabort>` to investigate.

Comment: @Alex, from my point of view, function X passes arguments.Search only to Y.  That would make it undefined in X.

Comment: @Alex, In catch block <cfdump var="Arguments.root"><cfabort> gives correct xml without any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not `var`-ing `childNode`, so you will be overwriting the outer call's variable with the recursive call's one. This will make the process unstable, and unsurprising that you get unexpected results / errors.

I imagine that's your problem.

Comment: Along those lines, make sure ALL of your function local variables are properly `var` or `local` scoped, or you will just run into the same sort of problem with other function variables.